# accessing static variables inside a function

Tags: php, function, static

let's say I call a static header title from my Page class like this

```
Page::$header->title[] = configuration('Site Name', '');
```

could I call it the same way in the function like this ?

```
class PageController {

public function index(){

Page::$header->title[] = configuration('Site Name', ''); //??

}

}
```

Comment: is `configuration()` a global function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as:

- `configuration()` is a global function
- You can load/resolve the `Page` class from inside the `PageController` class
- The `Page` class static property `$header` is initialize to an object with a property `$title` initialized to an array

You should be able to add elements to it as in your original example, however I'd suggest avoiding using `static` properties in PHP in general as they cause all manner of headache when trying to comprehensively unit test your code.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it...it make sense now